# Histogram with count on Y axis and binned scores per trial on x-axis

Tags: r

I have a database with three columns: one for participant number, another for trial number, and a last one with the score that the participant obtained in that trial.

I have 100 participants and 160 trials. I want to create a histogram that counts, for each trial, the number of participants that have scores between 0-2,2-4, 4-6 ... and superior to 16. I've tried doing this:

```
max(scores.data$value)
  
scores.data %>% ggplot(aes(score, fill = trial)) + 
  geom_bar(color = NA, position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5)) +
  scale_x_binned(limits = c(0,45), breaks = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,45), labels = c("2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","45")) + 
  labs(x = "time bins per trial",
       y = "count"
    
  ) + 
  facet_grid(~trial, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "lightgray", size = 0.25),
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text       = element_blank())
```

But I obtain this:

[image: histogram counting nº of participants for specific score bins for each trial]

This doesn't seem to be doing what I want and I've tried other ways and none is working. Any suggestions on how  can obtain a correct histogram?
I haven't been using R for a long time so I'm sorry if this seems very basic.

Thank you.

Here is some reproducible data using `dput(scores.data)`:

```
structure(list(participant = c("10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", 
"10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10000"), trial = 
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), score = 
c(5.409, 4.079, 4.355, 4.245, 3.43, 3.685, 4.808, 3.256, 7.038, 
3.714)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does the output of `ggplot(scores.data, aes(score)) + geom_histogram()` give you something closer to what you want to see?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

The  ggplot(scores.data, aes(score)) + geom_histogram() doesn't give me the counts by trial.

Here is a part of the data (for one participant and the first ten trials - in total I have 100 participants and 160 trials).

` structure(list(participant = c("10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", 
"10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10000"), trial = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), score = c(5.409, 
4.079, 4.355, 4.245, 3.43, 3.685, 4.808, 3.256, 7.038, 3.714)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those specific bins, you should `cut` your score data into those bins. I also converted your `trial` variable into a factor with the levels ordered numerically rather than alphabetically.

```
scores.data %>%
  mutate(
    binned_score = cut(score, breaks = seq(0, 16, by = 2), include.lowest = T),
    trial = factor(trial, levels = 1:10)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = binned_score, fill = trial)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(vars(trial), nrow = 2)
```

[image]